# Impedindo JFrame de ser movimentado na tela

Tags: java

Tenho um frame em java , e ele fica no meio a tela .
Não quero que ele possa ser movido para outros locais da tela como eu faria para definir isso ?

Answer (score 1):

Quem move janelas é o gerenciador de janelas, se você remover a barra de título, dificultará a movimentação, apesar de ainda ser possível por outras formas (no linux por exemplo, alguns gerenciadores de tarefas permitem fazer isso com a tecla `ALT`). Esta é a mesma abordagem usada nessas telas de abertura/carregamento de aplicativos como o Eclipse e IntelliJ.

Então, Se for possível deixar seu APP sem barra de título, faça:

```
jFrame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Não conheço outra solução.